# Restore a column in the database if it is blank

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, putty, restore

I ran a wrong command that removed the text from one of my columns `title`, but it kept some.

I need a Putty or phpmyadmin command that restores that column from my database backup **if** it is blank, and keeps the ones that already have anything in them as they are.

`(/var/backups/backup6.sql.gz)` (Database name: `Documents`, table `items`, column `title`

Answer (score 1):

With basic tools (assuming since you're using *phpMyAdmin*) restoring a single column from a backup is not possible.

You can, and that would be the most common practice, restore entire backup into a separate database and then copy the column data between the databases. Keep the space available in mind.

Depending on how big the backup file is and whether you could manually locate the `CREATE TABLE` (for table structure) and `INSERT` (for data) statements you're interested in, you may of course want to restore that single table in question only.